# Spring Boot 2.6.13 application immediately shuts down using command line to start

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tools:

- Windows 11
- Sprint Boot 2.6.13
- Command line
- openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_362-b09)
- OpenJDK Client VM (Temurin)(build 25.362-b09, mixed mode)

'Jar' file used

- spring-boot-2.6.13.jar

  spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.13.jar

  spring-boot-devtools-2.6.13.jar

  spring-boot-starter-2.6.13.jar

  spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.13.jar

  spring-context-5.3.23.jar

  spring-core-5.3.23.jar

  spring-expression-5.3.23.jar

  spring-web-5.3.23.jar

  spring-beans-5.3.23.jar

  spring-aop-5.3.23.jar

  commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

  spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar

Project structure
[Project structure img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLmaU.png)

"hello" folder to store the class file
[hello_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjLuR.png)

"config" folder to store the properties
[config_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5jVv.png)

`DemoApplication.java` is

```
package hello;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`HelloController.java` is

```
package hello;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello, world! ";
    }
}
```

`application.properties` is

```
# web port
server.port=8080
```

`Compile instruction` is

```
javac -d . -classpath spring-boot-2.6.13.jar;spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.13.jar;spring-boot-devtools-2.6.13.jar;spring-boot-starter-2.6.13.jar;spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.13.jar;spring-context-5.3.23.jar;spring-core-5.3.23.jar;spring-expression-5.3.23.jar;spring-web-5.3.23.jar;spring-beans-5.3.23.jar;commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar;spring-aop-5.3.23.jar; DemoApplication.java HelloController.java
```

`run instruction` is

```
java -classpath .;spring-boot-2.6.13.jar;spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.13.jar;spring-boot-devtools-2.6.13.jar;spring-boot-starter-2.6.13.jar;spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.13.jar;spring-context-5.3.23.jar;spring-core-5.3.23.jar;spring-expression-5.3.23.jar;spring-web-5.3.23.jar;spring-beans-5.3.23.jar;commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar;spring-aop-5.3.23.jar; hello.DemoApplication --spring.config.location=D:\\ideaProject\\Test\\Test\\Test_SpringBoot\\config\\application.properties
```

`run result` is

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.6.13)

[2024-01-15 14:55:18.255] - 81044 Inf [restartedMain] --- hello.DemoApplication: Starting DemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_362 on LAPTOP-3CQLL008 with PID 81044 (D:\ideaProject\Test\Test\Test_SpringBoot started by lenovo in D:\ideaProject\Test\Test\Test_SpringBoot)
[2024-01-15 14:55:18.278] - 81044 Inf [restartedMain] --- hello.DemoApplication: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2024-01-15 14:55:18.374] - 81044 Inf [restartedMain] --- org.springframework.boot.devtools.env.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor: Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[2024-01-15 14:55:19.387] - 81044 Inf [restartedMain] --- org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.OptionalLiveReloadServer: LiveReload server is running on port 35729
[2024-01-15 14:55:19.424] - 81044 Inf [restartedMain] --- hello.DemoApplication: Started DemoApplication in 1.832 seconds (JVM running for 2.359)
```

However, I can't use url "http://localhost:8080/" to open page

I have use `wmic process get name,executablepath,processid|findstr 81044` to find spring-boot process by PID 81044, but it doesn't exit.

Comment: Use maven or gradle to compile your project and create a runnable jar. Don't do it yourself, you are at least missing a ton of jars in your classpath.

Comment: Also, if you are on a new project, use at least Java 17 and Spring Boot 3: see end of life of Java https://endoflife.date/oracle-jdk and of Spring https://endoflife.date/spring-boot